# Array in array vue multiple select laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

I have an object that comes from the backend.

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "message": null,
  "data": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 41,
        "provider_name": "12312",
        "provider_bin": "123123123123",
        "contract_number": null,
        "contract_date": null,
        "provider_address": null,
        "provider_category_id": 5,
        "budget_classification_code_id": null,
        "provider_phone": null,
        "provider_head_name": null,
        "provider_call_centre": null,
        "sector_economies_id": 6,
        "calculation_type_id": 3,
        "region_id": 3,
        "additional_bank": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "providers_list_id": 41,
            "bank_id": 20,
            "bank_account_number": "3123123123123",
            "service_id": 6,
            "tariff_name": "31231231",
            "additional_bank_house": {
              "id": 1,
              "additional_bank_id": 1,
              "house_id": 4,
              "house": {
                "id": 4,
                "house": "23",
                "city": null,
                "region": null,
                "street": null,
                "street_type": null,
                "address": " , , ",
                "improvement_degree_title": null,
                "region_name": null,
                "city_name": null,
                "street_name": null
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I can pull out `additional_bank` through a loop. But inside it is `additional_bank_house -> house`, How can I get it out ?
So that I can let's add 1 element with house_id 5 (on the frontend it's a multiple select )

I would be grateful if you provide an example code that would allow you to pull data from `additional_bank_house -> house`, because if this succeeds, then they will automatically be substituted in multiple select

```
FRONTED: vue3
BACKEND: Laravel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this **:**

```
data.data.forEach(({ additional_bank }) => {
    additional_bank.forEach(({ additional_bank_house }) => {
    console.log(additional_bank_house.house.house)
  })
})
```

[`JSFiddle Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/frybs187/)

Comment: thanks, but the object is dynamic and goes in conjunction with others, respectively, everyone is driven in this way

Comment: But here we are iterating the response dynamically. so if you think in some of the nested objects few properties will be missing then you can use optional chaining operator. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining